# Ubuntu 22.04 dual boot with windows 11 randomly wifi gets disabled

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, iwlwifi

My PC specs:

```
pegasus@pegasus:~$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
```

```
pegasus@pegasus:~$ sudo dmidecode | grep -A 9 "System Information"
System Information
    Manufacturer: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
    Product Name: ASUS TUF Gaming A15 FA506IU_TUF506IU
    Version: 1.0
    Serial Number: L5NRCX026887212
    UUID: bf90dfa3-74b5-f54f-9d49-526152667a52
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number:  
    Family: ASUS TUF Gaming A15
```

```
pegasus@pegasus:~$ sudo dmidecode --type bios
[sudo] password for pegasus: 
# dmidecode 3.3
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.2.0 present.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 26 bytes
BIOS Information
    Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
    Version: FA506IU.320
    Release Date: 06/01/2022
    Address: 0xF0000
    Runtime Size: 64 kB
    ROM Size: 16 MB
    Characteristics:
        PCI is supported
        BIOS is upgradeable
        BIOS shadowing is allowed
        Boot from CD is supported
        Selectable boot is supported
        BIOS ROM is socketed
        EDD is supported
        5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
        Print screen service is supported (int 5h)
        8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
        Serial services are supported (int 14h)
        Printer services are supported (int 17h)
        ACPI is supported
        USB legacy is supported
        BIOS boot specification is supported
        Targeted content distribution is supported
        UEFI is supported
    BIOS Revision: 5.16
    Firmware Revision: 3.15

Handle 0x0033, DMI type 13, 22 bytes
BIOS Language Information
    Language Description Format: Long
    Installable Languages: 1
        en|US|iso8859-1
    Currently Installed Language: en|US|iso8859-1
```

I've a dual boot pc. With windows 11 and ubuntu 22.04.
My secure boot is turned off.
The problem is my pc keeps getting turned off randomly. And once it gets disabled it doesn't work again until I reboot my pc. and sometimes I need to reboot it multiple times to get the wifi as working again.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Looking at pictures of your device, it appears that the F12 key doubles as "airplane mode" switch. Is network back, if you press it? You may need to press it in combination with FN.

Comment: No. F12 turns on airplane mode if pressed with fn key. Otherwise I'm using it to change the language of my input

Comment: Please be clear the PC gets turned off or just the wireless?

Comment: the wireless gets disabled.